# Using DevicIOControl with VC#

Tags: c#, deviceiocontrol

I have created two different Visual C# dll's that make use of DeviceIOControl calls and I have defined them as below:

In first dll:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern BOOL DeviceIoControl(
    HANDLE hDevice,
    DWORD dwIoControlCode,
    ref Internal_COMMAND lpInBuffer,
    DWORD nInBufferSize,
    ref ulong lpOutBuffer,
    DWORD nOutBufferSize,
    ref DWORD lpBytesReturned,
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);

public struct Internal_COMMAND
{
    public ulong Address;
    public ulong Command;
};
```

In second dll:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern BOOL DeviceIoControl(
    HANDLE hDevice,
    DWORD dwIoControlCode,
    ref char[] lpInBuffer,
    DWORD nInBufferSize,
    ref char[] lpOutBuffer,
    DWORD nOutBufferSize,
    ref DWORD lpBytesReturned,
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);
```

But now I have to make them as a single dll within the same class. So I tried to use the below.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern BOOL DeviceIoControl(
    HANDLE hDevice,
    DWORD dwIoControlCode,
    ref char[] lpInBuffer,
    DWORD nInBufferSize,
    ref char[] lpOutBuffer,
    DWORD nOutBufferSize,
    ref DWORD lpBytesReturned,
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);
```

as common definition and passed the variables by converting structure to character array. But the driver does not work as expected

Please guide me with the correct procedure to follow

Comment: What on Earth was the point of not posting the code that matters??  Throw that code away, it is broken and completely unnecessary.  The C# language supports method overloads, works just as well when they have an attribute.

Comment: @HansPassant  Hi... It works as you said I used method overload.... Sorry being so dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method overload just worked just as @Hans Passant pointed out

This means I can use both definitions in a single .cs file and method overload takes effect, allowing to use the same function with different parameters